# Add callback to existing migrate field mapping

Tags: migrations

I have a use case where I want to use the [callbacks functionality](https://www.drupal.org/node/1133448) for the body field in a D6->D7 migration using [migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) and [migrate_d2d](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) modules. However, according to the above-referenced docs page, this is done when you are adding a new field mapping:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('destination_field', 'source_field')->callbacks('my_callback');
```

not adding to an existing mapping. How can I add a callback to an existing mapping? Do I have to remove and then re-add the mapping, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some debugging and looking at code, it turned out to be pretty easy. All of the mappings are [MigrateFieldMapping](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/migrate/tree/includes/field_mapping.inc?id=7.x-2.6#n9) objects in $this->codedFieldMappings, so it's just a matter of getting a reference to that object and calling the [callbacks() method](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/migrate/tree/includes/field_mapping.inc?id=7.x-2.6#n179). For example, to add a callback to the body field, you would use:

```
$this->codedFieldMappings['body']->callbacks('my_callback');
```